# is it possible to register eventloop in node addon?

Tags: node.js, node.js-addon, node-async

AtExit hook is a function that is invoked after the Node.js event loop has ended but before the JavaScript VM is terminated and Node.js shuts down. AtExit hooks are registered using the node::AtExit API. Similarly is there any way to register eventloop run in node addon?

Answer (score 0):

From a C++ addon, I think you need to interface with [libuv](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/api.html) for this.

From JS, you might find something useful in the new [async hooks](https://nodejs.org/api/async_hooks.html) API. You can also do work in the next event loop run with [`process.nextTick`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback_args).